# Correct way of approaching multi-app project with Git (cordova)

Tags: android, ios, git, cordova, ionic-framework

I wish I could just ask this question in a sentence, but I'm not that concise:)

I developed a cordova app which I turned into a git repo. Later this app turned into 30+ apps -- all basically the same with branding differences.

I decided the approach to use would be to leave my original app as the 'master' and then create branches for each of the branded versions. I would always make edits to 'master' and then pull/merge those changes into each of the branches. They all share 98% of the same code, so that seemed to make sense.

By and large it seems to work ok (on app #2) but I am running into a really annoying thing I can't figure out.

Each time I switch between branches, the platforms/ios and platforms/android directories get bunged up with extraneous files. Since the apps are branded/named differently, some directories/extra files carry over. Even when I go through and remove them I still can't build without errors unless I:

`- ionic platform rm ios
- ionic platform add ios`

...which is simple enough but I then have to move all kinds of custom native code files in place.. and it seems like I should be able to manage this better.

I tried adding the 'platforms' directory to .gitignore but then ran into other issues. I may have to revisit that method, but is there a recommendation for how I should structure these apps that all use most of the same code?

Comment: Adding platforms to .gitignore was a good idea.  You probably want to start there.  What were the problems you ran into?  I've managed a code base for an app that was branded over 3000 times.  What I did was create a build system that would generate the source code based on a database containing unique info for each brand.  Basically a custom build system.  Separate branches may get out of control on you one day.

Comment: Thanks! The issue with .gitignore was that I would pick up artifact files from other builds as I switched branches. I have switched back to that though. Based on your comments I have changed my build approach. I will still use branches, but each time I checkout a branch, I automatically zip up my current platforms directory and store it in an archive,  then switch to the new branch and grab its zipped code from the archive, unzip in place and automatically update the custom ios/android native code that may have changed. Sounds complicated, but it's made my life easier...